# Apollo GraphQL mutation signature equivalent to PUT

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to effectively do a PUT request with GraphQL

Mutation:

```
export const UPDATE_CAT = gql`
  mutation updateCat($catRef: RefInput, $payload: CatInput) {
    updateCat(ref: $catRef, input: $payload) {
      ${ref}
    }
  }
`;
```

Query variables:

```
{
  "catRef": {
    "id": "7b342789-e527-42a6-997b-cfe2fb6bdb07",
    "typename": "cat.beacon.Beacon"
  },
  "payload":{
    "position": null,
  }
}
```

Although this seems to wipe all of the props on the cat entity (it does not delete the resource). Is this the correct syntax for a PUT like request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's worth to note that graphql is protocol agnostic. That means any transport protocol can be used, not necessarily HTTP (despite HTTP is used in most cases).

Also, what do you mean by PUT like request? As I understand, you state that HTTP PUT method is used to patch data. Which might not be true. It depends on how you implement this. You can easily create a REST API that is accepting data via GET and sending via POST or PUT method despite this is not recommended by best practices.

The same situation here with your problem. It's not about your mutation signature, it's about mutation resolver implementation.

In order to make this work, you should determine in your resolver function on a server if this is a new or existing resource and handle both scenarios properly.

How can you check if this is a new resource? Id prop will be undefined in this case, right?

If you are working with third-party api then check it's docs.